# OpenID Error while testing asp.net app in My Developer Center

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am testing an application I developed using the .NET Devkit 2.0. In My Developer Center I am trying to run the connection tests in the Testing Your App section of the page. The OAuth test works fine but when I try to test OpenID I am getting an error.

When I click the "Test subscribe to app from Intuit App Center (OpenID)" it brings me to the company connect page, then I select the company, then it brings me to a free trial page of my App. 
When I click "authorize" I am getting a 404 Error.

The URL points to:
 `https://myserver.com/Error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/myapp/OpenIdHandler.aspx`
Where myserver is the name of my development server and myapp is the name of my application.

I am able to run the application from Visual Studio without a hitch. It connects and runs as expected but when I try it in the dev center it doesn't work properly.

Are my application settings correct? 
Should I be pointing to OpenIdHandler.aspx in this instance?

App settings in the dev center:
App URL: `https://myserver/myapp/Default.aspx`
Disconnect Landing URL: `https://myserver/myapp/Disconnect.aspx`
Manage Users URL: `https://myserver/myapp/Default.aspx`
OpenID URL: `https://myserver/myapp/OpenIdHandler.aspx`

This is my first run at publishing to the Intuit App Center so any suggestions would be a huge help. I'm not even sure if the settings in the dev center are the problem or not.
Thank you

Comment: Derrick, there is not enough info to go on here, but it looks like an error on the OpenIdHandler.aspx page as it is redirecting to the error page. You should debug that page and get the error message so we can further help you.

Comment: Is there a way to debug through the intuit dev center? I don't have any problems when I run it on my development server on my local machine so I'm not sure how I would debug this unless there is way to do it through the dev center.

Comment: From the 404 not found error, it seems that your path to the OpenIdHandler page is incorrect (OpenID URL).  Can you navigate directly to that URL without a 404?

Comment: I cannot. The Url bar shows this:
https://hindsiteoffice.hindsitesoftware.com:2323/Error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/hindsiteq/OpenIdHandler.aspx

Comment: My firewall was not set up properly so it was not allowing any traffic to hit the desired pages of the site. Seems very curious to me that I was able to go to the default page but no others. Any way, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

My firewall was not set up properly so it was not allowing any traffic to hit the desired pages of the site. Seems very curious to me that I was able to go to the default page but no others. Any way, it works now.